# How to scroll only with the Trackpoint, without using the middle mouse button in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, scripts, software-recommendation, xinput, trackpoint

I have long been used to the keyboard and touchpad design, and the Trackpoint on my new laptop is pretty much useless due to my existing habits.

Is there a way to make the Trackpoint directly scroll **without** pressing the middle mouse button on Ubuntu 18.04.5?

I have tried searching online but with no results. `xinput --list-props` doesn't have such an option. I think I might need a script or some other software to do this, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: Doesn't two-finger scroll work on the touchpad?

Comment: yes, it does, but I wanted to use the trackpoint to scroll

Comment: I don't have a trackpoint to test this out, but it does look entirely possible:. https://superuser.com/a/878318/440143